# Pandas: Remove duplicate dates but keeping the last

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

`(not a duplicate question)`

I have the following datasets:

```
GMT TIME, Value
2018-01-01 00:00:00,    1.2030   
2018-01-01 00:01:00,    1.2000 
2018-01-01 00:02:00,    1.2030   
2018-01-01 00:03:00,    1.2030   
.... , ....
2018-12-31 23:59:59,    1.2030
```

I am trying to find a way to remove the following:

- `hh:mm:ss` form the datetime
- After removing the `time (hh:mm:ss)` section, we will have duplicate `date` entry like multiple `2018-01-01` and so on... so I need to remove the duplicate date data and only keep the last date, before the next date, eg `2018-01-02` and similarly keep the last `2018-01-02` before the next date `2018-01-03` and repeat...

How can I do it with `Pandas`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have data:

```
              GMT TIME  Value
0  2018-01-01 00:00:00  1.203
1  2018-01-01 00:01:00  1.200
2  2018-01-01 00:02:00  1.203
3  2018-01-01 00:03:00  1.203
4  2018-01-02 00:03:00  1.203
5  2018-01-03 00:03:00  1.203
6  2018-01-04 00:03:00  1.203
7  2018-12-31 23:59:59  1.203
```

Use `pandas.to_datetime.dt.date` with `pandas.DataFrame.groupby`:

```
import pandas as pd

df['GMT TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['GMT TIME']).dt.date
df.groupby(df['GMT TIME']).last()
```

Output:

```
            Value
GMT TIME         
2018-01-01  1.203
2018-01-02  1.203
2018-01-03  1.203
2018-01-04  1.203
2018-12-31  1.203
```

Or use `pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates`:

```
df['GMT TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['GMT TIME']).dt.date
df.drop_duplicates('GMT TIME', 'last')
```

Output:

```
     GMT TIME  Value
3  2018-01-01  1.203
4  2018-01-02  1.203
5  2018-01-03  1.203
6  2018-01-04  1.203
7  2018-12-31  1.203
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `duplicated`

```
#df['GMT TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['GMT TIME']).dt.date

df[~df['GMT TIME'].dt.date.iloc[::-1].duplicated()]\
```

Or using

```
df.groupby(df['GMT TIME'].dt.date).tail(1)
```